# Trying to get my player to transfrom.flip python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, transform, flip

I am struggling with pygame. I want my player to move and face right or left when I press the right or left key respectively. Instead it just flips. I don't know how to make it point to the left, or right and then walk.

```
run = True

while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                swordsman = pg.transform.flip(swordsman, True, False)
                x += speed

            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                swordsman = pg.transform.flip(swordsman, True, False)
                x -= speed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either check the state of the keys with [`pg.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to see if <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> are pressed (as in the example below) or alternatively, change the `speed` variable to another value in the event loop and then change the `x` position (`x += speed`) each frame in the while loop not in the event loop (reset speed to 0 when the key is released).

With regard to the image flipping, keep a reference to the original image and assign it to the `swordsman` variable. When the player wants to move in the other direction, flip the original image and assign it (just assign the original image if they move in the original direction).

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
# This is the original swordsman image/surface (just a
# rectangular surface with a dark topleft corner).
SWORDSMAN_ORIGINAL = pg.Surface((30, 50))
SWORDSMAN_ORIGINAL.fill((50, 140, 200))
pg.draw.rect(SWORDSMAN_ORIGINAL, (10, 50, 90), (0, 0, 13, 13))
# Assign the current swordsman surface to another variable.
swordsman = SWORDSMAN_ORIGINAL
x, y = 300, 200
speed = 4

run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                # When the player presses right, flip the original
                # and assign it to the current swordsman variable.
                swordsman = pg.transform.flip(SWORDSMAN_ORIGINAL, True, False)
            elif event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                # Here you can just assign the original.
                swordsman = SWORDSMAN_ORIGINAL

    # Check the state of the keys each frame.
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    # Move if the left or right keys are held.
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        x -= speed
    elif keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        x += speed

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    screen.blit(swordsman, (x, y))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked exaclty as i hoped too! Tho i fully didi'nt understand what was going on!

Answer (score 1):

Is a `swordsman` a `pygame.Sprite` object? If it is, it should contain a `pygame.Rect` object in itself. Variable `x` is just a single variable, and its change has no effect on your `swordsman`. Try `swordsman.rect.x = x`

Comment: *If it is, it should contain a pygame.Rect* No, that's wrong. While you can call `get_rect()` on a `Surface`, the resulting `Rect` will only describe its size and has nothing to do with where it will be drawn on the screen. You're thinking about a `Sprite`, which in fact combines a `Sprite` and a `Rect`.